# Why does the Keyboard not show when editing UITextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I have a ios8 project in XCode 6.1 using size classes. At somepoint in development, the Keyboard stopped displaying while editing a UITextField. To debug, I made simple UIViewController with a single UITextField in a different storyboard in the project, and the keyboard would not display for that UITextField either.

I then made an entirely new project and a simple UIViewController and a single UITextField and the keyboard DID work correctly.

I've looked at all the settings in the project and could find nothing that looks like it affects the keyboard.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Are you seeing this only in the simulator, or on the real device too?

Comment: If this is the simulator, use the proper keyboard menu option under the Hardware menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happen only in the simulator then go to

**Hardware Menu->Keyboard->Toggle Software Keyboard**

or use shortcut key

**cmd+k**

Answer (score 0):

Go to simulator -> Hardware then

[image]

[image]

then click on Toggle Softwate Kwyboard, then you will get key board for TextField